# Prevent reload on form submit javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit

I have the following form:

```
<form> Enter Session ID: 
<input type="text" id="session_number" name="session_number"/>
<button onclick="persist()"> Persist </button>
</form>
```

And the following persist function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function persist(){
  console.log("hererer");
  var session_number=document.getElementById('session_number');
  console.log(session_number);
  return false;
}
```

How can I prevent the page to be reloaded when the button is clicked?

Comment: `<button type="button" onclick="persist()">Persist</button>`

Comment: Change button `type` to `submit`. Add the event listener to form (on submit) instead of to button (on click). Also invoke `event.preventDefault()` inside `persist` callback to prevent default behavior of HTML forms when submitted.